# SSDT 2017 Setup Failed The configuration registry key could not be opened

Tags: ssis, installation, visual-studio-2017, business-intelligence, ssdt-bi

We have been using VS 2017 Shell version for BI development for a few months without problems but today it stopped unexpectedly and restarted on its own. After the restart, we got an error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Wizards' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

After some googling, one of our developers decided to uninstall and re-install SSDT for VS 2017 from the Microsoft site, but the setup fails:

> The configuration registry key could not be opened(0x800703F3)

I googled some more and found that a force uninstall could help but it did not.

Here is the part of the setup log when errors started:

```
[1F4C:3708][2018-05-08T17:40:36]e000: Error 0x800703f3: Process returned error: 0x3f3
[1F4C:3708][2018-05-08T17:40:36]e000: Error 0x800703f3: Failed to execute EXE package.
[2EBC:3250][2018-05-08T17:40:36]e000: Error 0x800703f3: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[2EBC:3250][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package SQL Server Analysis Services (id: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices)
[2EBC:3250][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i319: Applied execute package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, result: 0x800703f3, restart: None
[2EBC:3250][2018-05-08T17:40:36]e000: Error 0x800703f3: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1F4C:3708][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i329: Removed package dependency provider: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices
[1F4C:3708][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i351: Removing cached package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\
[2EBC:3250][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall progress: 100
[1F4C:3708][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[1F4C:3708][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}
[1F4C:3708][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i352: Removing cached bundle: {f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}\
[1F4C:3708][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f55a890f-6c82-4455-9bb5-2a902cdb7d87}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2EBC:3250][2018-05-08T17:40:36]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: The configuration registry key could not be opened (0x800703F3)
[2EBC:3250][2018-05-08T17:40:36]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x800703f3, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems someone know a solution for this:

> Michael Mallit [MSFT] · The versions should be 1.15.3227. So please
>   uninstall any VS instances, then uninstall the VS Installer through
>   Add/Remove programs and verify C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer is removed and/or empty.
>
> Thanks, Mike

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246732/ssdt-1560-installer-the-configuration-registry-key.html

Hope i've helped!

Comment: This did the trick, we first uninstalled version 2017 as that was the corrupted one, but it didn't help. We then did the same with version 2015 and it worked, somehow the old version was preventing the setup to run properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Had same issue, this worked for me:

1.) Uninstall VS 2017.

2.) Uninstall VS Installer.

3.) Go to the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\' in Command Prompt and execute 'InstallCleanup.exe -f'.

4.) Delete all remaining files and folders having 'Visual Studio' in their name.

5.) Open https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017 to download and install a 15.6 version of VS.

6.) Open https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017 to download and install the latest SSDT.

Comment: Hi, this is the first solution we tried but it didn't work, now we realize we also needed to the the same with VS 2015 (an old instance that we still had on that server).

Comment: Its not fixed, the problem persists

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded SSDT for VS2017
Open CMD and ran the following commands

```
CD %userprofile%\Downloads
SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /layout
```

When the download was finished there is a Payload folder
I installed each of the components manually for SSIS which were

```
vsta_setup.exe
Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.VSIX
SSDTISSingleton.msi
SSISOneDesigner2012.msi
SSISOneDesigner2014.msi
SSISOneDesigner2016.msi
```

Works in VS2017 now. Will do until MS gets it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Microsoft is working on a fix.

See:

- [SSDT 15.6.0 Installer - The configuration registry key could not be opened (0x800703F3)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246732/ssdt-1560-installer-the-configuration-registry-key.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me based on what John Altamura wrote in:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246732/ssdt-1560-installer-the-configuration-registry-key.html

1. I uninstalled my SSDT using Visual Studio installer
2. I uninstalled Visual Studio using the Visual Studio installer
3. I then went to Add or Remove Programs and uninstalled everything that looked like it was related to Visual Studio
4. Then I had to actually re-download the VS installer from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/, as I needed the InstallCleanup.exe program in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\". This step is only needed if you uninstall VS Installer before running Installcleanup.exe.
5. Run InstallCleanup.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\"
6. Uninstall VS Installer from Add or Remove Programs.
7. Then to be safe I deleted this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
8. Then I restarted my PC.
9. Download Visual Studio 2017 from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
   Just in case I performed a minimal install from VS Installer, of only installing a single language pack
10. Then download SSDT from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017 and install
    Then, it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for this:)

First uninstall all VS components that you have already installed.

Run VS17 installer again and select the required components. Exclude all the SSDT components from vs17 installer(Don't select ssdt components). Now go for installation.

After successful installation of visual studio, Run the SSDT installer with selected components(SSIS,SSRS,SSAS) for the above installed VS. Hopefully it will get succeeded as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a VS update that fixes this issue.